# Correctly display data from AJAX (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code on back-end controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EmailsList()
    {
        var itemsEmail = db.InvitationMails
            .Select(x=> new
            {
                Email = x.To.ToString(),
                Name = x.Name.ToString(),
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(itemsEmail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This on AJAX call code

```
<script>
$('#save_quest').click(function () {
    email_update();
});

function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
           // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++){
                var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' + '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' + result.Email + '<b>' + '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' + result.Name + '</b>' + '</div>'
                $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Code works well,but I have `undefined` on View.

[image]

How I need to edit my code to display it correctly?

Comment: Do like this result[i].Email and result[i].Name

Comment: Yes. Thank's dude @BasantaMatia

Comment: Happy to know that it's solved your issue. You can mark as answer my solution to help someone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this to help someone if he/she get the same issue,

Because of it's an array of objects, so you need to add [i] with your result inside your for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++)
  {
   var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' + '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' + result[i].Email + '<b>' + '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' + result[i].Name + '</b>' + '</div>'
   $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
  }
```

Cheers :)